# Bandwidth Rate Limiter

Tags: networking, software-rec, internet, connection, bandwidth

I have 6 windows (XP/7) computers on a network which only has a 2mb line. We occasionly get times when one of the computers take up the entire line and everyone else hangs. I believe a rate limiter to limit each computer to a certain amount would solve the problem and was thinking of getting some software that would limit the computer to 1mb.

Does anyone have any recommendations for rate limiting software for Win XP/7?

Comment: This would probably be something you'd want to implement on your router rather than at each computer.

Comment: I can't do that because the network is managed by an external company and don't have access to extra hardware. So a software approach is the only option.

Comment: It sounds like they're *not* managing the network then. If you have issues, they should be fixing them. A software approach on the computer is going to suck because either it will have to be manually adjusted or people will have half bandwidth even when nobody else is using the network. Are there specific applications that cause this problem?

Comment: don't get me started, this is why i have had to result to this option.

Comment: we need more details of your network setup, "a network" is not much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not free, the solution that always worked best for me when it comes to bandwidth limiting, is [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also setup a free gateway (if you have a spare PC) such as clearOS, pfsense, ebox, etc, all of them can do traffic shaping.